Animated apocalyptic web series
I believe I saw this in early to mid-2000's. I think it was online and might have been a youtube series. I remember that each episode was only a few minutes long.
It was an animated american (not exactly cartoon, but computer animation) show that would eventually take place all over the US. It started out with the protagonist (who I think had glasses and kinda looked like Snowden). It was apocalyptic - but I don't think it was a zombie apocalypse - taking place in this time period. I think people were just missing. I remember the protagonist stumbled across cults and other religious groups. I also remember there were something like 100 episodes.
I don't recall there being any famous voice actors or anything. 
Edit: I also remember technology not working really well, so the protagonist had to walk everywhere. 

can you describe what the animation looked like?

My memory is hazy - I'm not sure if it was actually animated or if it was sort of like a slide show. It was computer animated, almost like video game graphics (like maybe the resident evil games in the late 2000's).

Well this is interesting. Is it possible this was a TV-short? MTV had shorts back then, Aeon Flux springs to mind.

No, it wasn't Aeon Flux and it wasn't on TV, I don't think - definitely not MTV. It was something that I watched online.

I figured it out. It was Afterworld.

